# cURL : Could not resolve host: xx.com [ping xx.com ok and xx.com is my local domain]

Tags: php, curl, dns

```
function curl_upload($post_url, $post_data) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $error ? $error : $result;
}

$data = curl_upload('http://xx.com/lists', $condition);
echo $data;exit();
```

then run the php code ,show me:

sometimes show `Could not resolve host: xx.com`

sometimes show the right data

i try to solve it，i google it ，but not work. so i ask here for help.

ping xx.com  ok

my resolv.conf:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 114.114.114.114`

myhosts:

/etc/hosts:
`xx.com 127.0.0.1`

who can give me help ,Tks!!

Comment: What are you trying to curl? It would appear that you are either blocked or the URL you are trying to curl has limits to how much you can hit their service.

Comment: xx.com  is my local domain,no limit